# Замена System.Text.StringBuilder: чем эта реализация лучше или хуже на самом деле?

Tags: c#, строки

Прав ли я в том: Что заменяю StringBuilder таким образом? Пожалуйста, если у вас достаточно знаний и навыков для этого, я с нетерпением о них узнаю, тут не имеет значения насколько они профессиональны)

```
static class Wholemy {
    #region :>-DirectString->:
    /// <summary>Представляет элемент стека строки в прямой последовательности элементов.</summary>
    public unsafe class DirectString {
        private static readonly System.Reflection.MethodInfo FastAllocateString = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(FastAllocateString), System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static, null, System.Reflection.CallingConventions.Standard, new System.Type[] { typeof(int) }, null);
        /// <summary>Содержит нижний элемент стека строки.</summary>
        public readonly DirectString Below;
        /// <summary>Содержит отдельное значение стека строки.</summary>
        public readonly string Value;
        /// <summary>Содержит общее количество символов стека строки.</summary>
        public readonly int Count;
        /// <summary>Содержит порядковый индекс элемента стека строки.</summary>
        public readonly int Index;
        /// <summary>Реализует элемент стека строки.</summary>
        private DirectString(DirectString stack, string value) {
            Below = stack;
            Value = value;
            if (stack != null) {
                Count = stack.Count + value.Length;
                Index = stack.Index + 1;
            } else {
                Count = value.Length;
                Index = 0;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>Возвращает корневой элемент стека строки.</summary>
        public static implicit operator DirectString(string value) {
            if (value != null)
                return new DirectString(null, value);
            return null;
        }
        /// <summary>Возвращает дополненный элемент стека строки из указанной строки.</summary>
        public static DirectString operator +(DirectString stack, string value) {
            if (stack != null) {
                if (stack.Value == "") {
                    if (value == "" || value == null) {
                        return stack;
                    } else {
                        return new DirectString(stack.Below, value);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (value == "" || value == null) {
                        return stack;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (value == null) {
                    return stack;
                }
            }
            return new DirectString(stack, value);
        }
        /// <summary>Возвращает дополненный элемент стека строки из указанного массива символов.</summary>
        public static DirectString operator +(DirectString stack, char[] value) {
            var chars = value != null ? new string(value) : null;
            if (stack != null) {
                if (stack.Value == "") {
                    if (chars == "" || chars == null) {
                        return stack;
                    } else {
                        return new DirectString(stack.Below, chars);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (chars == "" || chars == null) {
                        return stack;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (chars == null) {
                    return stack;
                }
            }
            return new DirectString(stack, chars);
        }
        /// <summary>Возвращает массив элементов стека строки в обратной последовательности элементов.</summary>
        public string[] Items {
            get {
                var index = Index;
                var array = new string[Index + 1];
                var stack = this;
                while (stack != null) {
                    array[index--] = stack.Value;
                    stack = stack.Below;
                }
                return array;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>Возвращает комбинацию стека строки в прямой последовательности элементов.</summary>
        public static implicit operator string(DirectString stack) {
            if (stack != null)
                return stack.ToString();
            return null;
        }
        /// <summary>Возвращает комбинацию стека строки в прямой последовательности элементов.</summary>
        public override string ToString() {
            var tstack = this;
            var tcount = Count;
            var result = (string)FastAllocateString.Invoke(null, new object[] { tcount });
            fixed (char* target = result)
            {
                while (tstack != null) {
                    var svalue = tstack.Value;
                    fixed (char* source = svalue)
                    {
                        var scount = svalue.Length;
                        while (scount > 0)
                            target[--tcount] = source[--scount];
                    }
                    tstack = tstack.Below;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    #endregion :<-DirectString-<:
    static void Main() {
        DirectString test="";
        test+="Проверка ";
        test+="дополнения ";
        string result=test + "строки";
    }
}
```

В качестве альтернативного способа реализации есть альтернативный метод, для этого целевая программа должна быть обработана рекомпилятором [Wholemy.Ril](http://wholemy.ru/ril/):

```
[Ril.Method]
public override string ToString() {
    var tstack = this;
    var tcount = Count;
    var result = (string)FastAllocateString.Invoke(null, new object[] { tcount });
    tcount *= 2;
    fixed (void* target = result)
    {
        while (tstack != null) {
            var svalue = tstack.Value;
            fixed (void* source = svalue)
            {
                var scount = svalue.Length * 2;
                tcount -= scount;
                Ril.Cpblk2(Ril.Add(target, tcount), source, scount);
            }
            tstack = tstack.Below;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

По поводу выше представленного кода, если вы заметили, он собирает строки в неизменяемый стек, а результат выводит по средствам метода ToString(), остальные методы не имеют с выводом ничего общего, так как инициируют добавление значения обернутое в элемент стека, тем или иным образом. Прикол этих манипуляций в том, что для большинства операций не происходит бессмысленных операций копирования памяти, а все используемые значения остаются в том виде в котором они добавлены в этот стек, то есть можно формировать достаточно сложную последовательность одних и тех же данных, как например составление текстового документа из компонентов, а затем однократно получать результат на любой стадии его пополнения в виде одной целой строки.

Элемент реализован таким образом что его можно свободно перечислить по значению его переменной Below. Но главная фишка в том, что может существовать множество различных ветвлений, как например продолжение документа в том или ином случае сразу во всех версиях без дополнительных затрат, то есть фактически можно создать заранее подготовленные шаблоны, на время выполнения того или иного метода, так как держать их в таком виде где-либо еще лишено смысла. Естественно, что один из результатов может просто напросто не выводится в конечную строку в связи с отсутствием удовлетворяющих одно из ветвлений условий, в этом случае как вы понимаете отбрасываются исключительно элементы стека, а не совершенные операции копирования, которые по многим представлениям могут занимать львиную долю времени выполнения. Следует так же отметить, что это все можно легко дополнить различными преобразованиями прямо в конечный поток вывода, минуя вывод в виде строки, так как в таком элементе нет скрытых переменных.

Этот способ исполнения настолько прост и эффективен, что он используется не только для строк, обширность применения этого способа никак не может быть оспорена, особенно таким аргументами как целостность. Так как абсолютное большинство элементов такого рода остается внутри выполнения методов.

Этот вопрос не имел бы права на существование, если бы не одно но, я до сих пор имею дело с огромным количеством кода, который лишен таких подходов, то есть существуют огромные тяжеловесные конструкции, которые зачастую лишь тратят время моего процессора и бессмысленно насилуют мой мозг, заставляя переделывать этот код под свои привычки и правила, то есть это не исправимо. И все это происходит долгие десятилетия, нет мне конечно все равно, я переделаю ваш открытый исходный код, но знайте, вы только и сделали что потратили мое время, причем не так чтобы мало, это валовая выемка) И да, попробуйте поспорить с тем, кто двадцать лет пишет программы именно в таком формате постоянных преобразований) Я ржу, да-да)

По поводу тестирований в лоб, такие как консольные анализаторы сделанные на коленках с рандомным потоком вложений, не тратьте время зря, так как вы и сами не используете так StringBuilder, потому это не отражает реальную картину. Попробуйте заменить его там где вы сами логически представляете наилучший результат и вот это как раз и сравнивайте, мне же ваши сравнения ничего не дают, вы делаете это прежде всего для себя, так как я для себя их уже сделал, но в любом случае спасибо за вашу попытку, анализ это главное.

Кроме того, если вы имеете возможность сделать замену цикличного копирования на опкод **cpblk**, то результаты немного другие. Мы же с вами хорошо понимаем, что ситуация немного сложнее чем кажется с первого взгляда. Да и одним С# для этого сложно обойтись, чтобы порвать каноны Микрософт аналога, который так же содержит скрытые "**читкоды**", они же **IL** коды)) Мне временами кажется что Микрософт сделала для этого все, дабы пользователь не создавал отсебятину лучше чем их бесконечно правильные творения, попадая в неминуемую зависимость от стандартов пакета .NET Framework, но он не лучше если вы способны читерить так же.

Люблю читать комментарии! О эти сравнения, о эти домыслы, не стесняйтесь) Я вам обязательно отвечу, если вы успеете об этом прочитать, до тех пор как дискуссия не попадет в чат, в любом случае по двадцать раз на одно и тоже я не буду отвечать, тут главное успеть задать вопрос и получить ответ вовремя) Если вы конечно не собираетесь отвечать, а только спрашивать) Главная цель, расставить негласные точки над и, потому как гласные тут явно не стыкуются) Продолжайте, не стесняйтесь я с удовольствием прочту ваши гласные в одна тысяча первую ночь, хотя их намного больше, скорее десять тысяч первую)

Comment: А какая цель преследуется: экономия памяти, уменьшение сборок мусора, увеличение производительности, что-то ещё?

Comment: А вот ответ на вопрос, увеличивается ли производительность, вы можете получить только при помощи профилирования. Мозговой штурм в таких вопросах — штука бездоказательная. Выберите свою модель (типы, объём) входных данных.

Comment: @ШумВесьмой так задавайте вопрос. вопрос - это "как решить проблему X?". А у вас сейчас просто кусок кода, который вообще непонятно зачем написан - может быть проблема была в том, что вы решили поразмять пальцы, и написать экран кода - тогда да, вы, очевидно, правы - ведь ваш код решил проблему )

Comment: 1. Вопрос плохо подходит под критерии stackoverflow, на него нельзя дать однозначный ответ. 2. В разных версиях .NET класс StringBuilder имеет разную реализацию. Начиная с .NET 4.0 внутри используется список, похожий на вашу реализацию. 3. Ваш код напоминает так называумую RopeString. Только у вас не хватает самого важного: методов вставки, удаления, замены - а именно при их использовании может быть большой эффект от строки-верёвки.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31263/discussion-on-question-by----system-text-stringbuilder--).

Answer (score 16):

Бездумное использование связных списков при живой сборке мусора — обычно плохая идея. Сборщик мусора очень не любит собирать связные списки. Да даже без сборки мусора связные списки раскидывают данные по памяти, что тормозит программу из-за невозможности использовать кэш.

Так как ваш `StringDirect` добавляет элемент в связный список при добавлении строки абсолютно любой длины, то написание худшего сценария очевидно:

```
public void TestStringDirectChars ()
{
    StringDirect sb = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        sb += (char)(i % char.MaxValue);
    sb.ToString();
}
```

Аналог на `StringBuilder` и простом массиве:

```
public void TestStringBuilderChars ()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        sb.Append((char)(i % char.MaxValue));
    sb.ToString();
}

public void TestOptimizedPerfChars ()
{
    char[] sb = new char[100000];
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
        sb[i] = (char)(i % char.MaxValue);
    new string(sb);
}
```

Результаты бенчмарка:

```
TestStringBuilderChars:   0.6   (ticks: 2085)
TestStringDirectChars:    6192  (ticks: 20014990)
TestOptimizedPerfChars:   0.5   (ticks: 1626)
```

Как можно видеть, на сборку строки в 100К `StringDirect` тратит безумные 6 секунд, в то время как `StringBuilder` справляется за полмиллисекунды. Это я ещё не вытерпел построения мегабайтной строки: если `StringBuilder` запросто справляется с этой задачей, то `StringDirect` только и делает, что генерирует несобираемый мусор.

---

Впрочем, давайте рассмотрим предлагаемый вами сценарий: сборку из уже готовых подстрок.

```
private readonly Random _rnd = new Random(0);
private readonly List<string> _strings = Enumerable.Range(10000, 100)
    .Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();

public void TestStringBuilderStrings ()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        sb.Append(_strings[_rnd.Next(_strings.Count)]);
    sb.ToString();
}

public void TestStringDirectStrings ()
{
    StringDirect sb = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        sb += _strings[_rnd.Next(_strings.Count)];
    sb.ToString();
}

public void TestOptimizedMemStrings ()
{
    var sb = new List<string>(100000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        sb.Add(_strings[_rnd.Next(_strings.Count)]);
    string.Concat(sb);
}
```

Здесь последний тест — сохранение идеи экономии памяти (экономия на спичках, если моё мнение интересует), но реализация без связных списков, используется банальный динамический массив.

Смотрим результаты:

```
TestStringBuilderStrings: 3.2   (ticks: 10524)
TestStringDirectStrings:  6.8   (ticks: 22054)
TestOptimizedMemStrings:  4.9   (ticks: 16034)
```

То есть ваш класс даже на случае, оптимизированном специально для него, в два раза медленнее универсального `StringBuilder`. И даже самая прямолинейная реализация через `string.Concat` выигрывает и по скорости, и по памяти.

---

Итого: сценариев, в которых ваш класс хоть сколь-нибудь выигрывает у простых, универсальных и прямолинейных решений на базе встроенных классов, обнаружено не было. Если у вас такой сценарий есть, то поделитесь.

[image]

Полный пример: http://pastebin.com/FkqVQ8Ya

Comment: Интересно, а я могу тут писать? Не говорите так много о сбоке мусора плохого, а то вдруг ваши собственные программы перестанут работать, тьфу тьфу тьфу)

Comment: У вас есть возможность протестировать заново, с небольшими поправками, ну или большими, тут уж на ваше усмотрение)

Comment: Тут я вас не буду хватать за руку и убеждать чтобы вы попробовали мой рекомпилятор, тут каждый сам решает, что ему делать) Думаю в ваших планах этого небыло, но вы всегда можете тоже самое сделать постаринке, декомпилировав тестовую программу ildasm, вставить опкоды и скомпилировать ilasm, я не сомневаюсь что вы на это способны)

Comment: @ШумВесьмой Я так и не услышал ответа на вопрос, в каком случае ваш билдер оптимален.

Comment: Я пользуюсь такого рода элементами, сколько себя помню с 2001 года походу дела, когда начал C# изучать после VB. Эти средства незыблемы с моей точки зрения) К С++ я плохо отношусь, он мне никогда не нравился, на нем мой отец тока программил, а я искал способы уровнять MC++ с С#. В моем случае он оптимален везде где существуют быстрые задачи, с неизвестным размером заранее. Где может быть пара десятков элементов за раз, но естественно без ограничений)

Comment: Я до сих пор остаюсь не согласен с вами, в моем уме ничего не меняется по этой теме) Разве что, вы используете неправильные тесты и запускаете бессмысленную нагрузку) То есть нагрузка не специализирована, а потому врет безбожно) Но я в то время создал конечный продукт на основе этого и мне он нравится, правда я не хочу им тут делиться, нафиг не нужно, работает и ладно)

Comment: Я вам штуку поинтереснее предлагаю глянуть: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1475947.WholemyCSharpStyle-18984 Может вы и в этой штуке обнаружите все самое плохое для вас) Во всяком случае, надо как-то эту штуку пиарить, мне мало зла) Скучно, нет конкуренции ни с кем)

Comment: Чтобы никто не гадал, куда делся проект по предыдущей ссылке, добавляю новую: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Wholemy.CSharp

Answer (score 4):

Если вопрос - это

> Прав ли я в том: Что **заменяю StringBuilder** таким образом

то ответ - "скорее всего нет"

Конкретно в моей области и на моем стеке - web/asp.net mvc/sql server - вы неправы. Потому что string builder-ы в ней почти не используются, и экономия на них - совсем никакая.

Более того, сам факт использования String Builder для сборки хоть сколько-то значимой по размеру строки - это почти наверняка ошибка. Потому что накопление строки в памяти вместо отправки в Response - это потеря времени, памяти и производительности. Вся работа со сколь-либо значимыми объемами данных должна использовать stream-ы.

А за самописный String Builder, требующий кастомного постпроцессора, у web-разработчика сразу же отрывают руки. Такие дела.

---

В другом качестве (не замены String Builder-а, а каком-то еще) - ваш класс возможно и хорош. А возможно и нет - кто ж знает.

Comment: Это все к тому, что я очень часто мыслю либо стеком, либо связанными элементами, либо двоичным деревом, массивы употребляются в моем случае исключительно с заранее известной длинной, никаких запасов, никаких копипастов, четко по размеру, я по другому не научусь этим пользоваться, это выработка, есть у этой логики и значительные минусы, но плюсов очень много с моей точки зрения, значительно больше чем их видите вы)

Comment: @ШумВесьмой да мыслите как угодно, хоть шестигранной змейкой - это не делает ваш код заведомо лучшим, быстрым, легкочитаемым и безбажным.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что это способ мысли прежде всего) Многие проекты не предусматривают иного способа мысли) И вы представляете что получается, когда одну логику пытаются реализовать на другой логике, а я вам скажу, бесконечное количество немыслеммого кода) Потому что простоту усложняют до маразма, чтобы получить тот же самый результат наисложнейшими методами скрытыми от глаз, но только потому что их не видно, они не становятся лучше)

Comment: На этой шестигранной змейке построено множество компонентов, в том числе и то чем вы пользуетесь, на уровне isapi, это уже выше, то есть ближе к вашему уровню восприятия, логика искажается и начинается высокоуровневая шехерезада)))

Comment: @ШумВесьмой т.е. вы наивно полагаете, что я знаю только как готовые классики из фреймворка использовать? забавно слышать такое от человека, который даже профайлером не умеет пользоваться, и не знает про существование ref src :) ну ок, наслаждайтесь своей "гениальностью", не буду вам мешать. Ваш код при этом как был ничем не обоснованным никому не нужным велосипедом, так и остался.

Comment: О да, вы даже не представляете до какого ничто я могу дойти) И тогда мы посмотрим кто никчемнее в нашей суровой реальности) Хотя конечно спасибо вам за это, пойду конвертить строки в символьные массивы) Будет ноль проблем с внутренними объявлениями) И этот класс точно мне пригодится) Вы не волнуйтесь мы с вами пересеклись возможно только для того чтобы я сделал очередной решительный шаг в ничто)

Comment: Меня то ничто не ограничивает, в отличии от вас я не пишу на дядю и могу воротить что захочу исходя из загонов в свои углы)

Comment: @ШумВесьмой какое отношение это имеет к вашему вопросу и моему ответу?